# How to migrate cassandra cluster column change

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

We have a use case to change cassandra table column (change the type from Int to Long), since it not supported changing from Int to varInt is supported and we are fine with that.

But in some of the tables this column is a cluster column and we have no way of changing this.

I am curious what is the best way to handle this case.

Comment: I have the same problem and the page at:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html#concept_ds_wbk_zdt_xj__cql_data_type_compatibility
says that int->varint should be possible.

Comment: Well, I've checked-out Cassandra code and it seems the documentation is wrong. You can not change the clustering column type.

Comment: In case of CLUSTERING column, method AlterTableStatement.validateAlter(CFMetaData, ColumnDefinition, AbstractType<?>) checks isCompatibleWith method, which is not implemented in IntegerType and Int32Type, so it defaults to Type checking which is for these two types FALSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not alter a clustering column in Cassandra - you'll need to make a new table and load the data into that table using a third party application (cqlsh `COPY` being the simplest, or something like Spark). If you're unable to tolerate a change in the table's name, you'll need to backup your data, drop the old table, and recreate it with the proper types.